# Why does this smoothscript javascript create a white space at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html

He there,

i have made a smootscroll script, but when i implement it, there is a large white space at the bottom, can anyone help me out? When i delete the javascript, it works fine, i have no clue what is happening. I have already tried to console.log the values, but can not find anything strange here...

```js
jsScroll = document.getElementsByClassName('pageScroll')[0];
currentPixel = window.pageYOffset;

var speed = 0.1;
var offset = 0;

function smoothScroll() {
  offset += (window.pageYOffset - offset) * speed;
  var newPixel = offset;
  var diff = newPixel - currentPixel;
  jsScroll.style.transform = "translateY(-" + offset + "px) translateZ(0)";
  currentPixel = newPixel;

  requestAnimationFrame(smoothScroll);
}

smoothScroll();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="pageScroll" class="pageScroll">
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
    <p>test
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

any help will be appreciated, Thank you

Comment: Consider closing your HTML tags. Whilst you don’t need to, it can be the cause of unintended bugs.

Comment: When you look at the page in the Inspector - where does the whitespace come from - is it a border, a margin or padding? Which element(s) does the whitespace belong to?